# converting the 2D Heat equation from cartesian to polar coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I have the Heat equation in the form:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\alpha\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}\right)\tag{1}$$
And I would like to convert it to polar (spacial) coordinates. I have start off by saying:
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\right]\tag{2.1}$$
Then working about that:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[r^2]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[x^2+y^2\right]\Rightarrow \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\cos\theta\tag{2.1A}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\tan\theta\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac yx\right]\Rightarrow \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}=-\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\tag{2.1B}$$
Now subbing back in I get:
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\cos\theta-\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\right]\tag{2.2}$$
Now splitting it up again I got:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\cos\theta\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right]\cos\theta+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\cos\theta\right]\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$$
$$=\cos\theta\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right]\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right]\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\right)+\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial[\cos\theta]}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial[\cos\theta]}{\partial\theta}\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\right)$$
$$=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2}\cos^2\theta-\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r\partial\theta}\frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta}{r}\tag{2.2A}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}\right]\frac{\sin\theta}{r}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\sin\theta}{r}\right]\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}$$
$$=-\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial\theta^2}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{r^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r\partial\theta}\frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta}{r}-2\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}\frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta}{r^2}\tag{2.2B}$$

Its quite long and I'm getting a bit lost, could anybody confirm if what I've done is correct and that I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are right upto (2.2). When you are calculating $\frac{\partial(\cos{\theta})}{\partial x}$, you can use the substitution $\cos{\theta} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. So,

$$\frac{\partial(\cos{\theta})}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \right] \\
= \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.1 - \frac{x.2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{x^2+y^2} \\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} - \frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\
= \frac{1}{r}  - \frac{\cos^2 \theta}{r} = \frac{\sin^2{\theta}}{r}
$$

There is one error in your calculation, $\frac{\partial \cos \theta}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} = \frac{\sin{\theta}.\sin{\theta}}{r}$. Similarly, while calculating $\frac{\partial \sin{(\theta)}/r}{\partial x}$, we can substitute,

$$ \frac{\partial \sin{(\theta)}/r}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right) \\
= \frac{(x^2+y^2).0 - 2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \\
= -\frac{2}{x^2+y^2}. \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\
 = -\frac{2}{r^2}\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}
$$

I find it easier to calculate it this way rather than substituting so many variables. Finally,
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = \left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r^2} \cos^2 \theta + \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{r}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2}\left(\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2} \sin^2 \theta + \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} 2\sin \theta \cos \theta  \right) $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\big(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \cos \theta - \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\frac{\sin \theta}{r}\big) = $$

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} \cos^2 \theta - \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r \partial \theta}\frac{\sin \theta \cos \theta}{r} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\frac{\sin \theta \cos \theta}{r^2}$$
It's a little hard to follow as we split it up into pieces differently.
If you could label the left sides of your equations it would be easier to see what you are calculating, just name them $A$, $B$, etc to save on typing.

Comment: ok, I will add my new working to my question, It seems more correct but I believe I am making a mistake calculating the derivatives themselves

Comment: I've just added it as a new answer as the question was getting very long

Answer (score 0):

I have tried doing it another way:
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right]$$
$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right]$$
$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right]\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right]+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\right]\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}+\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right]$$
$$=\frac{\partial^2r}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r\partial\theta}\right)+\frac{\partial^2\theta}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}+\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r\partial\theta}+\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\right)$$
$$=\frac{\partial^2r}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{\partial^2\theta}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}+\left(\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\right)^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}+2\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r\partial\theta}$$

---

Then I found that:
$$\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}=-\frac{\sin\theta}{r} &
\frac{\partial^2\theta}{\partial x^2}=\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{r^2}\\
\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}=\frac{\cos\theta}{r} &
\frac{\partial^2\theta}{\partial y^2}=-\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{r^2}\\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\cos\theta &
\frac{\partial^2r}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\sin^2\theta}{r}\\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}=\sin\theta &
\frac{\partial^2r}{\partial y^2}=\frac{\cos^2\theta}{r}
\end{matrix}$$